# How to exclude some folder in node_modules from building in angular prod build

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an app using angular 9. I am trying to exclude a particular folder(lib) inside node_modules from getting minimized during ***ng build --prod***. 
[image]
I am doing so because lib folder contains already minimized files and production build is minimizing that again which leads to breaking of functionalities in may app. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: [X-Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): please show us how you imported the files you're talking about.

Comment: I just included the lib folder in package.json as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

Hi i hope this will help. You can use the `cpx` library for the same. Link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx

In the scripts in package.json:

```
"modify-highstock": "cpx \"modifications/highstock.d.ts\" \"node_modules/highcharts\""
```

The above script will replace the file "node_modules/highcharts"  with "modifications/highstock.d.ts".

Like wise you can remove the files as well.

So you can use:

```
"build": "npm run modify-highstock && npm run 4g-mem-limits && npm run build-glapp",
```

The script you have to run before taking the build.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any other way? Doesn't seem to work for me.